# What is the problem with having a hash to group function where you can find a discrete log relation between 2 different hashes?

Tags: hash, group-theory

I was reading some notes on a naive hash to a group function.

Consider a cryptographic Hash function $$H: \{0,1\}^{*}\to \{0,1\}^{k}$$

Consider a Discrete Log Hard Group $G$ with a generator $g$. We can build a Hash to group function $$HG(a) = g^{H(a)}$$

(We raise $g$ to the numerical representation of the Hash output)

Apparently, the problem with this is that it's easy to find a relation between 2 hash outputs of this Hash to the group function.

Assume two inputs, $a_1 \& a_2$

Let numerical representation of $H(a_ 1)$ in $Z_n$ be $n_1$

Let numerical representation of $H(a_2)$ be $Z_n$ be $n_2$

$HG(a_1) = g^{n_1}$

$HG(a_2) = g^{n_2}$

Let ${n_1}^{-1}$ be inverse of $n_1$ in $Z_n$.

Let $c = n_2 \cdot {n_1}^{-1}$

Now ${HG(a_1)}^c = {g^{n_1}}^c = g^{n_1\cdot {n_1}^{-1}.n2} = g^{n_2} = HG(a_2)$

So we can now find a relation between Hash to Group of $a_1$ & $a_2$.

$HG(a_2) = {HG(a_1)}^c$

---

I understood up to this. However what is the problem if you can find a relationship like this? Can this be used to attack the Hash to Group function in some way?

Comment: @kelalaka - I didn't say there is a problem with the cryptographic hash function. I am asking what is the problem with a Hash to Group function built this way.

Comment: @kelalaka - edit my question & title to make it more clear.

Comment: edited, i mean ***

Comment: You should add the context where this attack makes sense especially for `I was reading some notes on a naive hash to a group function.` part.

Comment: @kelalaka - that's my question - why is it a problem having a hash to group function built like this? Why is it problematic if one can find a relation. The notes I am reading use this example as motivation for using a Pedersen Hash for building a Hash to group function because then one cannot find such a relation if you use a Pedersen hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many schemes that use a hash to group function will be broken if such a relationship can be found. A good example of the problem might be the [Boneh-Franklin IBE scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boneh%E2%80%93Franklin_scheme) where $H_1$ is required to be a secure hash to group function.

Public keys in this scheme are computed as $H_1(ID)$ so for example Alice's public key might be $Q_A=H_1({\tt"Alice"})$ and Bob's might be $Q_B=H_1({\tt"Bob"})$. Note that $Q_A$, $Q_B$, $n_A$ where $H_1({\tt"Alice"})=n_AG$ and $n_B$ where $H_1({\tt"Bob"})=n_BG$ are known to everyone.

Now, Alice's private key is supposed to be $d_A=sQ_A$ where $s$ is a secret known only to the central authority. However, Bob with knowledge of $d_B=sQ_B$ can compute $d_A$ because $d_A=sQ_A=s(cQ_B)=c(sQ_B)=cd_B$ where $c=n_A/n_B$ modulo the group order.

Comment: What is the difference of $Q_A$ and $n_A$? The OP used multiplicative notation, it is better to be stick to that.

Comment: Apologies the definitions of $n_A$ and $n_B$ were typed in haste and now corrected. I've used additive notation to make comparison with the B-F article easier.

Comment: What exactly does $H_1({\tt"Alice"})=n_AG$ mean? How do I calculate $n_A$? Do I find $H_1({\tt"Alice"})$ & then scalar multiply it by the inverse of the generator to get $n_A$?

Comment: I am confused because when one introduces a new term like $n_A$, one first introduces  it in the left hand side of an equation but here you directly use it in the right hand side

Comment: @user93353 The conditions of your question says that I can find the discrete log relation of a hash. $n_A$ is computed by whatever means the discrete log is found in your assumption.